# How to combine 2 string arrays for every possible combination

Tags: matlab

I want to obtain all possible combinations from two string arrays. For example if'

```
a = ['Hello', 'World']
b = ['Hey', 'Earth']
```

I want to output

```
c = ['Hello','Hey';...
     'Hello','Earth';...
     'World,'Hey';...
     'World,'Earth']
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is not a `string` array, it is a `char` array. To be a string array you need the quotes `"`, so `a = ["Hello", "World"];`.

For combining, just do a double loop:

```
a = ["Hello", "World"];
b = ["Hey", "Earth"];

rowNumber = length(a) * length(b);

C = strings(rowNumber,2);
rowCounter = 0;
for i=1:length(a)
    for j=1:length(b)
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1;
        C(rowCounter,1) = a(i);
        C(rowCounter,2) = b(j);
    end
end
```

As an alternative, you could try the `ndgrid`, but this is less efficient since it computes and stores the grid values both by computing `A`, `B` and when combining them to create the array `C`:

```
[A,B] = ndgrid(a,b);
C = [A(:) B(:)];
```